# Silverlight 4 Textbox validation only after change

Tags: silverlight, validation, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, data-annotations

Im developing a solution in Silverlight 4 with RIA Services.  I am using data annotations on my entity to describe validation.  I can see these are reflected on the client side code after building.  I have a child window which has textboxes bound to a single entity record for editing.  The data annotation i have on all the textboxes is the  annotation but this does not ever fire until a user has editted a textbox first, left the textbox, re-entered the textbox and then deletes the content.
This has no use if i am trying to force someone to fill in a textbox as they may skip straight over the textbox with the required data annotation.

Am i missing something simple here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When should it fire, then? If you want to force someone to fill textboxes, you can check whether the object is valid after the button is pressed.

Comment: How do you test it?  On my submit i am testing if the child window Entity.HasValidationErrors which returns false which i would expect to return true when a RequiredField is not populated.

Comment: You should call validation methods explicitly. There are 2 of them: `Validator.TryValidateObject` and `Validator.ValidateProperty`. Also set the `ValidatesOnExceptions` property to true at binding.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this very effective solution without any issues in both SL3, 4 and 5, thanks to Thomas Claudius Huber: http://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/blog/2009/07/17/here-it-is-the-updatesourcetrigger-for-propertychanged-in-silverlight/